# Convert start_date to end_date to an array/# and Update nested table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Users will input a **start_date** and an **end_date**

I need to insert every date within this range into a table which **belongs_to user**

At the moment I just have the standard update code in the **user_controller.rb**

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      redirect_to @user, :notice  => "Successfully updated user."
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
```

I'm sure it's pretty easy to iterate through the dates and dump them in a hash but I have no idea how assign it back to the **params[]**

Anyone got any ideas on how I should approach this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make a method in the User class:

**user.rb**

```
def save_dates(start_date, end_date)
  date = start_date
  while date <= end_date
    user_dates.create(:the_date => date) # class UserDate, belongs_to :user
    date += 1.day
  end
end
```

**user_controller.rb**

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    @user.save_dates(params[:user][:start_date], params[:user][:end_date])
    redirect_to @user, :notice  => "Successfully updated user."
  else
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
end
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution but it should work. If you want to move it completely into the Model and use a callback, you'll have to create virtual attributes on User for start_date and end_date:

**user.rb**

```
attr_accessor :start_date, :end_date
validates_presence_of :start_date, :end_date
after_update :save_dates
def save_dates
  date = start_date
  while date <= end_date
    user_dates.create(:the_date => date) # class UserDate, belongs_to :user
    date += 1.day
  end
end
```

**user_controller.rb**

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    redirect_to @user, :notice  => "Successfully updated user."
  else
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried both methods and neither seems to be passing the start_date and end_date the method **save_dates**. Could this be because they're nested in @user.table.start_date? Do I need slightly different syntax?

Comment: Yes... in `user.rb`, whenever it says `start_date` or `end_date`, it's referring to the instance of User. So you can think of it as `@user.start_date`. Therefore you would need to change it to `table.start_date` and `table.end_date`.